# Salesforce 1 new event don't show the record type selection

Tags: salesforce1-app, record-type, event

When I set up record types for the event , I can choose my record types from the desktop , however when I test the salesforce 1 , after I click the new event button the app directly jump to the edit new record page with the default record type , and I cannot choose which record type to create.
Are there any good advises?